# Inconsistency downloading multiple files with nodejs but not with php

Tags: php, node.js, download

[image: Difference downloading multiple files with nodejs and php]

I coded a script on both nodejs and php which achieve the same thing, ping an API, retrieve a list of files, loop through each file and download them to disk to a specified location.

On the left is by nodejs, and on the right by php.

I observe that, certain files randomly fail to download on each attempt in nodejs. And on a certain attempt, all files would succeed as well. While on php, each attempt is consistent and all files get downloaded fine.

Is there something am missing in nodejs, i.e. a configuration/header that isn't included by default through requests to download file? Or does downloading multiple files needs to be handled differently in nodejs?

Nodejs code:

```
const http = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

function getResponse(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, response => {
        let body = '';

        response.on('data', data => {
            body += data
        })

        response.on('end', () => {
            callback(JSON.parse(body))
        })
    })
}


var download = function (url, dest, callback) {
    http.get(url, response => {
        response.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
            .on('close', callback)
    });
};

getResponse('https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?page=1', json => {
    json.data.forEach((item, index) => {
        download(item.path, `files/file-${index}.jpg`, function () {
            console.log('Finished Downloading' + `file-${index}.jpg`)
        });
    })
})
```

PHP code

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->get('https://wallhaven.cc/api/v1/search?page=1');

    $json = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());

    $rows = $json->data;

    foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
        $content = file_get_contents($row->path);

        Storage::put("files/file-$index.jpg", $content);
    }

    return 'done';
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors anywhere?

Comment: No programmatical errors. But using wireshark, I get out of order packets when downloading via nodejs

Comment: Forgot to mention, the JS script remains stuck indefinitely. If I would use a module such as axios and set a timeout in the config, it would then generate an error saying the request spent too long past the defined timeout.

Comment: Could it be that because nodejs is powered by V8, it then behaves same as Chrome does? For when I open multiple files in the same way, some files do get corrupted/do not display in the same way.

Comment: You should also check for errors on the request object: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Process is probably getting stuck indefinitely because you may be getting an error thrown in the pipe function, that is either leaving the read/write stream dangling. Try adding an error handler to your file write stream and see if that provides more information. (That could also identify why you may be getting incomplete/ corrupt files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic header that will make it work in Node.js. If sometimes it works, and other times the request took too long, the server might be silently dropping the request due to rate-limiting.

The difference that I can make out that PHP is synchronous and is downloading each file one by one into memory and then placing into a file, whereas in Node.js you immediately fire every single request and handle them all at once, streaming contents into files. Receiving packets out of order packets is normal, the TCP protocol is there to make sure that they get put back together again. Node.js is capable of something like this, you're most likely hitting a security feature of the server or another limitation.

If time is not an issue, I would suggest modifying your Node.js slow down the requests, either by limiting the number of concurrent requests or doing them one by one (easiest option, see `async/await`, promises, the axios library). Following up on your Reddit post, learning C++ to complete this task will most likely not yield any benefit. In fact, it would be orders of magnitude more difficult. Node.js is a really powerful platform capable of much more than downloading files.

Without knowing the true cause of the problem, I can't offer any more advice apart from trying to analyse your requests and understand where they are going wrong.